# How to restore lots of files deleted by mistake in Dropbox efficiently?

Tags: dropbox

I just deleted **a lot of** files and folders in Dropbox by mistake, and it had been synchro.

I know how to restore them one by one on the web, but it seems too troublesome. So I wonder how to restore them efficiently.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via the API if you want. Check out the delta endpoint. There is a nice blog post on this

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/blog/23

Cheers!

Comment: if you do not know the cursor is there a way to either find out the cursor or get the full list?